# Full-stack application + API in Symfony2 - best approach

Tags: rest, api, symfony

I would like to ask anyone who has done it before. I have a full-stack (application logic + templating, etc.) application written in Symfony 2.x. I now need to add REST API to what I have currently and I would like to avoid mixing these two, because the API would then need to load twig and plenty of other components / bundles, which would definitely affect the performance. So far I identified three ways I can do this:

1. Write a separate application (this would require a lot of refactoring to decouple parts of my current application to make them reusable by this new API app).
2. Use new environment (let's call it "api" for now).
3. Use new kernel (e.g. ApiKernel).

While the first one is quite obvious to me, but at this time not really feasible. The next two are somehow ambiguous to me. From Symfony docs:

> Whereas environments execute the same application with different configurations, kernels can execute different parts of the same application.

So I can imagine Kernel scenario, it has separate front controller, loading new kernel that loads its own configuration and registers its bundles. But with new environment, we can also load environment-specific configuration and register other set of bundles.

Which one would be better in terms of performance? (Assuming the full-stack app use few quite heavy bundles and about 15 3rd party bundles in total, whereas the API app would use 2-3 3rd party bundles and these will need to be lightweight). The minor factor here is maintanability.

In case you know other ways to handle this nicely, please do not hesitate to give your suggestions (with pros and cons compared to solutions listed above).

Comment: have you checked that it's really affecting your performance before starting any activities here?

Comment: yes, I have profiled current application for a while now. The initialization time is significant compared to total execution time (up to 70%). It has a lot of things the API does not need.

Comment: did you check it in *dev* mode with debug on or in prod as well with all optimizations that are there? honestly, we had struggled a lot with performance in the beginning with our REST api, but there are so many things you can do BEFORE ripping your app apart somehow.

Comment: I did test it in dev mode mostly, but I also tried in prod (with profiler enabled, I don't know how much the profiler affect the results). To be honest I don't have anything related to this API yet, so I am really keen to actually go this way and separate it (to some extent) from main app. Especially having in mind that most likely in some near future the full app will be replaced by the API completely and front-end will be built with a Javascript framework instead.

Comment: that's what we did. still I don't see why you're sure you have to do something here. go for a different 'env' I propose in addition with a new Kernel. but I would avoid still. good luck.

Comment: Well, it's not that I'm sure I have to do something. It's more that I like to do, because I feel tha API is logically a separate application and I would like it to be separately implemented as well. I did ask for performance here, but I just wanted to know which scenario will be more efficient. The decision of separating it was already made, what I wanted to ask is which approach seems better in terms of performance (and maintanable, but that comes as minor factor here). Anyway, thanks for contributing.

Comment: I just thought I'd let you know that I benchmarked two scenarios: one with separate kernel and one with re-using the same kernel. Results: 300% performance gain with a separate kernel before any refactoring & optimization.

Comment: I am happy for you. Never said it wouldnt work, but still if you profiled in dev only this does not tell the truth. But just go on with it, just a different Kernel to avoid additional dependencies is fine.